# Kill 'Invoke-webrequest' if it takes too long

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, invoke-command

I have a script I am using to download a file from the internet,

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri MyUrl -websession $session  -outfile $filename
```

I have this as a scheduled task to run on the hour, every hour. For the most part, this works perfectly. However, I have found that sometimes the command hangs and fails to download the file. Is there a way I can check if the command is taking more than a set amount of time to run and if it has, kill the command and start again?

I have tried the timeoutsec flag but it does not seem to do work at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell jobs. Example logic:

- Start Job
- Loop checking the job's State with Get-Job for a certain amount of time.
- If job takes too long, call Stop-Job
- If job finishes, call Receive-Job

Reading:
[Using Windows Powershell Jobs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs.aspx)